# weird resolving of path to command

Tags: mac, path, nano

I have the terminal editor 'nano' installed in two places on my mac

```
/usr/bin/nano

/opt/local/bin/nano
```

The installations are of different versions. The one in `/usr` does not support my configuration in `~/.nanorc` and the one in `/opt` does.

When I open a file with the command 'nano file', errors are displayed, indicating that the one in `/usr` was used, however, if I run 'which nano'; the one in `/opt` shows up.

Isn't `which' meant to search the path for the default? And why wouldn't a call to 'nano' resolve to the same path?

I made a work-around by adding the following line to `~/.profile`

```
alias nano='/opt/local/bin/nano'
```

Comment: The real question is, why do you have two executable files with the same name in directories *both* of which are in your `PATH` variable? Remove or rename one of the `nano` files to `nano.bak`, and if you still need the binary in both locations, create a symbolic link to the remaining binary.

Answer (score 1):

The binaries are hashed and resolved in the order their parent directories appear in the PATH environment variable. Adjust it according to your needs. This is true for my experiences with bash, at least. Consider looking at the man page for your shell and look for COMMAND EXECUTION and PATH if what I'm telling you does not apply to your shell.

For example, if I wanted `foo` to mean /home/me/bin/foo and not /usr/local/bin/foo then I would put /home/me/bin/ before /usr/local/bin in the path, where *before* means *left of*:

PATH=(...):/home/me/bin:(...):/usr/local/bin:(...)

The path is commonly set up in /etc/profile or in ~/.profile.

Comment: That is my understanding of it too. I am just wondering; why then does 'which' not display the right one? Isn't that utility meant to search PATH in order?

Comment: It should, and does. Have you tried hash -d nano? Have you looked at hash -l? This seems like one of those cases when one oversees something and thus gets unexpected results. I really don't think which works incorrectly on your system. What could be happening is that nano gets hashed to /usr/bin/nano before the one in opt is found. Apart from that I'm out of advice.